# Need help finding a function to return the heading of the maximum value of an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a spreadsheet that has the buy and sell prices of different widgets in 5 different regions (the regions are labelled A,B,C,D,and E.  I have created a function that finds the greatest of intraregional margin, ignoring 0's in L5 (the function being an array: `{=IF(MAX(IF(ISERROR(B5:F5/G5:K5),0,(B5:F5/G5:K5)-1))=0,"",MAX(IF(ISERROR(B5:F5/G5:K5),0,(B5:F5/G5:K5)-1)))}`

Now, the problem I am having is that I cannot figure out a formula to put in M5, that tells me which region has the highest Margin.  I'm think it would be some combination of the INDIRECT and ADDRESS functions, but I cant figure out the function to use with ADDRESS that returns the column I need.

Since I cant include a picture, I will have to describe the setup.  The names of the widgets start in A5 and run down.  Then `B` through F contain the sell prices for each widget in each different region.  Then `G` through K contain the buy prices for each widget in each different region. L has the formula that lets me know what the highest intraregional margin is.

Comment: We would need a screenshot or sample file to understand your question. You can upload a picture to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) and post the link as a comment or [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27413077/edit).

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, the array formula in the OP would not produce the correct results, I'd suggest a simpler:

```
 {=MAX(B5:F5-G5:K5)}
```

in L5 and copied down. To check the regions associated with the maxima I suggest a matrix, to allow for the possibility that more than one region achieves the maximum for any specific widget. So for example in M5 and copied down and across to suit:

```
=IF(B5-G5=$L5,"#","")
```

[image]